# How to handle DataGridView event CollectionChanged in VB.NET?

Tags: .net, vb.net, datagridview

I want to handle the CollectionChanged event of a simple DataGridView in my winforms application.
I can handle it with C# using the following code:

```
this.datagridview.DataBindings.CollectionChanged += DataBindings_CollectionChanged;
```

But how can i handle the event using VB.NET?
I can't access the DataBindings property inside my code the following way:

```
Private Sub handleCollectionChanged(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles datagridview.DataBinding.CollectionChanged
    ' do something
End Sub
```

I tried it with

```
Private WithEvents dataBinding As System.Windows.Forms.ControlBindingsCollection
Public Sub New()
    InitializeComponent()
    dataBinding = RadGridView1.DataBindings
End Sub
```

but that also doens't works.

Comment: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7taxzxka%28v=vs.100%29.aspx

Comment: Thx, i think that helps me. And also i found out, that my examples also works correctly, the problem is another: the CollectionChanged event raises only, if the collection of databindings behind has changed, not it the content of bound data has changed.

Answer (score 0):

Regarding my comment above:
i found out, that my examples works correctly, the problem is another: the CollectionChanged event raises only, if the collection of databindings behind has changed, not it the content of bound data has changed.
To handle changes on the datasource of an grid, you can handle the ListChanged event of your list of objects you used for your datasource.